# Should I use a low voltage magnetic dimmer or a low voltage dimmer for LED strips?

Tags: lighting, led

I just ordered a low voltage magnetic dimmer (Model # SLV-600P-WH) from Home Depot for $40 for undercabinet lighting I plan to do with flexible LED strips.  I understand that this  must be wired before a relatively expensive dimmer transformer [such as this one](http://inspiredled.com/dimmable-transformer-12VDC) for $65 to $100+.  Is it correct that I need a special low voltage transformer and not a cheap $15 transformer for this kind of dimmer?

If so, the thing is, why not just get a 12v LED dimmer [like this one](http://www.ledsupply.com/led-drivers/12v-wall-mount-pwm-dimmer) for $35 which presumably can be placed after a regular $15 transformer?

It seems like the majority of DIY sites assume one is going with the expensive approach.

Is there some advantage to going with the Low voltage magnetic dimmer and special transformer, even though it is far more expensive?  Or is it just as good to go the cheap route and use the low voltage magnetic dimmer for something else?

**One possible issue:** I've got a galley style kitchen, so there will be a run of wire about 12 feet going from one side to another.  Is either approach better suited for that kind of distance?